# incremental id as alphanumeric code

Tags: mysql, url, encode

I need to show id as alphanumeric code url friendly and not more than 8 chars. And this code shouldn`t be stored, but should be decodable to the original id value.

Something like ENCODE/DECODE pair, but url friendly. How can I do this?

Comment: What about just [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding it? You can use a variant that's more URL friendly by substituting two of the problematic characters.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use a 64-bit hash code. Algorithm in this stackoverflow post:
[Lightweight 8 byte hash function algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325125/lightweight-8-byte-hash-function-algorithm)