# ID Generation from 16 digit number

Tags: id-generation

Are there any possible simple methods/ways to generate/encrypt a 16 digit alpha-number into a 6 to 8 digit alpha-numeric code. There will be millions of possible combinations of the 16 digit number, so the encrypted 6-8 alpha-numeric number has to be unique. Thanks for your suggestions in advance.

Comment: *16 digit alpha-number into a 6 to 8 digit alpha-numeric code* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: What did you try or search for? Is your question a repeat of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325125/lightweight-8-byte-hash-function-algorithm ?

Comment: GUID perhaps is the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Let's do the math, it only hurts for a moment:

16 digits: 0-9 is 10 characters
10^16 = 10,000,000,000,000,000

alpha-numeric with 0-9a-zA-Z is 62 characters
62^8 = 53,459,728,531,456

Since
10,000,000,000,000,000
is greater than
53,459,728,531,456
then **no**.

But if you are willing to use a larger character set including accented characters, foriegn characters and perhaps emoji then yes.

If you use a character set with 100 characters
100^8 = 10^16
then yes.

If you use a character set with 465 characters
465^6 ~= 10.1^16
then yes.